# Android direction sensor

Tags: android, sensors, direction

is it possible to know which direction the phone is pointing while looking at the camera preview, or do you have to have the phone flat like a compass.

Thanks

Comment: You can get the direction it's pointing, and the rotation of the phone along the 3-axis sensors. So you can do anything you want.

Answer (score 8):

Yes - The following code should do the job

```
public class Test extends Activity  implements SensorEventListener{

    public static float swRoll;
    public static float swPitch;
    public static float swAzimuth;


    public static SensorManager mSensorManager;
    public static Sensor accelerometer;
    public static Sensor magnetometer;

    public static float[] mAccelerometer = null;
    public static float[] mGeomagnetic = null;


    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        // onSensorChanged gets called for each sensor so we have to remember the values
        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            mAccelerometer = event.values;
        }

        if (event.sensor.getType() == Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD) {
            mGeomagnetic = event.values;
        }

        if (mAccelerometer != null && mGeomagnetic != null) {
            float R[] = new float[9];
            float I[] = new float[9];
            boolean success = SensorManager.getRotationMatrix(R, I, mAccelerometer, mGeomagnetic);

            if (success) {
                float orientation[] = new float[3];
                SensorManager.getOrientation(R, orientation);
                // at this point, orientation contains the azimuth(direction), pitch and roll values.
                  double azimuth = 180 * orientation[0] / Math.PI;
                  double pitch = 180 * orientation[1] / Math.PI;
                  double roll = 180 * orientation[2] / Math.PI;
            }
        }
    }



    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager)getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
        accelerometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER);
        magnetometer = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_MAGNETIC_FIELD);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, accelerometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, magnetometer, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, accelerometer);
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this, magnetometer);
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i print the direction in log???? in which variable u r getting the direction???

Comment: @Mitesh The azimuth value is the one you should be looking to print. Log.d("direction", String.valueOf(azimuth)) should do the job.

Comment: @Richard I think if the user is using the camera and direction is to be calculated in this case then the azimuth value will just give a  different value from the original value because when using the camera the device is not parallel to the ground, so we have to consider other values as well to get the actual direction of the device